# Excel conditional formatting using generic formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to conditionally format cells in Excel. Is it possible to create a generic formula that does the following:

```
    IF the value in column A of the given row = "A" 
    AND the value in the given cell is greater than .1 
    AND the value in the given cell is less than 1
    THEN format the cell with a light grey background color
```

In the example below, I want the formula to apply to cells B1:K2, but I only want cells E1, I1 and K1 to be highlighted in grey.

[image]

Comment: Where could I find an example of such a formula? The examples I've seen test for a single condition and don't refer to the formatted cells in a generic way.

Comment: Which cells shall the conditional format rule apply to? Which is the "given cell" in your question?

Comment: I've updated the original question with the requested info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select B1:K[n]. B1 is the active cell.
- Then, click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule.
- In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, click Use a formula to
  determine which cells to format.
- Under Format values where this formula is true, type the formula:

  =AND($A1="A",B1>0.1,B1<1)
- Click Format.
- In the Fill box, select your light gray color.
- Click OK until the dialog boxes are closed.

Greetings

Axel

Answer (score 0):

Select cells `E1:F2,I1:I2,K1:K2` (hold down `Ctrl` while selecting discontinuous range) so the conditional formatting will apply to them.

The cell `K1` should have the focus, i.e. be highlighted with white background, while other selected cells are highlighted with dark background. Insert conditional formatting with following formula:

```
=($A1="A")*(K1>0.1)*(K1<1)
```

Comment: I want to select the entire range (B1:K2) but only have the cells that meet the above criteria turn grey.

Comment: @mariita - so C1 should have received this light-grey fill if the percentage was greater than zero (but less than 100%)?

Comment: but `G1` meets the criteria and should not be highlighted, I don't understand :(

Answer (score 0):

Tap *F5* and when the GoTo dialog opens, type A:K (◄ just like that) into the *Reference:* box and click OK. You should have columns A through K selected with A1 as the `Active Cell`.

Create a new Conditional Formatting Rule using the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* option and supply the following for *Format values where this formula is true:*

```
=AND($A1="A", A1>0.1, A1<1, ISODD(COLUMN(A:A)))
```

Click Format and select a light=grey *Fill* then click OK to accept the format and then OK again to create the new CF rule. Your results should resemble the following.

[image]

*Edit:* Revised from literal interpretation to subjective interpretation